# How do I prevent users from adding secondary groups to themselves?

Tags: linux, permissions

Or put differently, how do I a stop users from modifying their group membership?

A user who belongs to the [x-admin] group which is a sudo-er was able to add himself to the wheel group.

How can I set user/group so that they are not able to add secondary groups to themselves.

I think it would involve preventing them from using the usermod command.

Are there other options? Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need a narrower definition of what the group is allowed to do.  That goes into the sudoers file.

See this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/500679/block-a-command-from-sudo-user